# How to get firestore data in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My code is getting this error when I call readLocationData() in my initState():

> Unhandled Exception: type 'GeoPoint' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable'.

Not sure how to fix this one. My firebase Cloud Firestore has a list of 4 documents, each with a `GeoPoint` field called `geopoint`, each with a handcoded latitude and longitude.

```
  Future<void> readLocationData() async {


    var query = await Firestore.instance.collection('bakeries').getDocuments();

    List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> mainList = List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>();

    query.documents.forEach((doc) {

      List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> values = List.from(doc.data['geopoint']);
      print('geopoint' + values.toString() +'\n');

    });

    for(var i=0; i < mainList.length; i++) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = mainList[i];
      GeoPoint geopoint = map['geopoint'];
  print(geopoint.latitude.toString()+','+ geopoint.longitude.toString());
  }

  }
```

Comment: If you could say what line it is calling on that'd be helpful in diagnosing your error

Comment: It's the line 'List<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> values = List.from(doc.data['geopoint']);'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that a [`GeoPoint` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/GeoPoint-class.html) is not iterable, which is correct. I'm not sure what you expect `List.from(doc.data['geopoint'])` to return in that sense.

If you expect the latitude and longitude to be taken from the `GeoPoint`, you'll have to access those properties explicitly in your code. But event then I'm not sure what the `key` and `value` in your `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` would become.

Comment: Haha I was typing out this same answer as you posted it

Comment: Thanks! But how would one access the latitude and longitude in the code? I've been trying for days and can't get my head around it

Comment: Don't `doc.data['geopoint'].longitude` and `doc.data['geopoint'].latitude` work?